# Mac mail mail from cron

Tags: macos, email, bash, cron

```
From sandeep@Sandeeps-MacBook-Air.local  Fri Mar 23 20:04:23 2018
X-Original-To: sandeep
Delivered-To: sandeep@Sandeeps-MacBook-Air.local
From: sandeep@Sandeeps-MacBook-Air.local (Cron Daemon)
To: sandeep@Sandeeps-MacBook-Air.local
Subject: Cron <sandeep@Sandeeps-MacBook-Air> /Users/sandeep/Library/cootie.pl/cootie.pl cr
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=sandeep>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=sandeep>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/sandeep>
Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 20:04:22 +0530 (IST)

/bin/sh: /tmp/iu.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm getting this mail quite often. What is this about? Is my Mac ok? Do I need to update something or delete anything?

```
$ crontab -l
4 * * * * /Users/sandeep/Library/cootie.pl/cootie.pl cr
```

Comment: Your cron job is failing and sending you mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get mail from `cron` whenever a cron command fails. In such cases you can use

```
crontab -l
```

to see which commands `cron` executes. From there you have two options

- Run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` to edit your crontab and remove the offending line
- Fix the error in the script (`/Users/sandeep/Library/cootie.pl/cootie.pl` in your case)

Comment: how do i fix the script

Comment: @SandeepRanjan Do you still need it? If yes, maybe ask a new question asking for help debugging the script. Don't forget to include the script into the question, and link to the question here for reference.

Comment: ok i will add a new ques but where is script

Comment: @SandeepRanjan In `/Users/sandeep/Library/cootie.pl/cootie.pl` :-)

Comment: it did vim /Users/sandeep/Library/cootie.pl/cootie.pl   it gives me file with such charecters
  ^G^@^@^A^C^@^@<80>^B^@^@^@^S^@^@^@^H^K^@^@

Comment: @SandeepRanjan It's a compiled program then. As it doesn't work anyway, maybe just remove the line from your crontab. Or do you have any idea what `cootie.pl` is?

Comment: no i dont any thing about cootie.pl :/

Answer (score 1):

As @fd0 said in the comments, your cron job is failing.

When this happens, you receive that email with the error from the cron job.

> ```
> /bin/sh: /tmp/iu.sh: No such file or directory
> ```

That's the error from the execution of the cron job. You should inspect the script and ensure it executes successfully.

Comment: how do i do that.. ?